# Error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: java, android, kotlin, runtime-error

I have been getting this error lately after re-installing Android Studio on my pc. Anyone got a clue on how to fix it ?

https://gyazo.com/be54539661824450357d83980623e4f8

This is the Logcat:

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] 'C:\Users\joe\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProject\app\build\intermediates\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 57625483' returns error 'Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing 'install-create':
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:595)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3434)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstallCreate(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1561)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:232)
at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:5954)
at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1049)
at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:877)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4313)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5938)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
at com.android.internal.content.InstallLocationUtils.resolveInstallVolume(InstallLocationUtils.java:241)
at com.android.internal.content.InstallLocationUtils.resolveInstallVolume(InstallLocationUtils.java:152)
at com.android.internal.content.InstallLocationUtils.resolveInstallVolume(InstallLocationUtils.java:167)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSessionInternal(PackageInstallerService.java:803)
at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:592)
... 12 more''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Comment: You probably need to increase the emulated storage on your virtual device. I had an old API one that did that, I had to bump up the space a fair bit over what I thought it actually needed! Before I did that it would *sometimes* work though, so try a Cold Boot, maybe clear the cache (inside Android) or do Wipe Data if you're happy to do that

Comment: Alright, will give it a try! However, isnt there a way to make it automatic instead of having to increase space everytime it becomes full ?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't know a lot of the details about how it works though! If you create a new device, the *SD card* disk image is the size of the card you specified (like it's set aside the required amount of space) but the *user data* one is basically empty. So it doesn't need to allocate all the space you set in the config, and over time that image will grow (and the *Size on Disk* field in the AVD Manager will increase). But in my experience, it fills up even though I'm not using much space on the virtual device, until it hits the defined storage size

Comment: I don't know why that happens - at a guess, it's something about the system managing the storage, maybe treating it as solid-state memory and writing all over the drive (the disk image, really) for wear-levelling reasons. Because it doesn't know it's not a real mobile device - but if the emulator is being smart and not allocating space for the disk image if it hasn't been used, but the device is writing all over it (even though most of it is "empty") then the file size would grow. I'm just speculating but yeah

Comment: But no I don't think there's a way to make it redefine the storage space available to the device automatically. I used to try and keep that number low, since I'd only be using a few hundred MB anyway, but it just seems to cause problems

Comment: "But in my experience, it fills up even though I'm not using much space on the virtual device, until it hits the defined storage size" - Yes I noticed that as well. Did some quick tests and its seems to be consistent, but I am pretty sure it is not supposed to do that. Maybe it can be reported as a bug!

Comment: Alright I got you. Guess I will have to wipe it more often then when toggling between projects. Its unfortunate because before i re-installed android studio I did not have this problem. It used to automatically increase the space for every project I added so it was not known to be something I had to do manually. I did however force wipe data now and then when there was too many projects. Anyway, Hopefully they will fix it in the future! Appreciate the feedback!